# DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE(‘SQL Plans’) deletes all ad-hoc and prepared plans, not just single-used ones

Tags: sql-server, plan-cache, query-cache

Kimberly Tripp's blog post [here](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/plan-cache-adhoc-workloads-and-clearing-the-single-use-plan-cache-bloat/) made me think that running DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('SQL Plans') clears just single-used ad-hoc and prepared query plans. But that seems incorrect. It clears all. Which is probaly not a good option to go if you have high average use count of prepared plans.

Is there any option to clear JUST ad-hoc plans? Not the prepared ones?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @plan_handle varbinary(64)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT plan_handle
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans
WHERE objtype = 'Adhoc' 

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @plan_handle  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (@plan_handle);  
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @plan_handle 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, later. Many thanks. I'll probably add usecounts = 1 to the filter.

Answer (score 2):

I had come up with this a while back. It's not far off from the above code, just plopped into a stored procedure with some filters on it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[clear_single_plans]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#plan_handles')
IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #plan_handles
END

CREATE TABLE #plan_handles(plan_handle VARCHAR(1000));

DECLARE @plan_handle_command VARCHAR(1000) = '';

INSERT #plan_handles ( plan_handle )
SELECT DISTINCT 'DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (' 
                 + CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), decp.plan_handle, 1) 
                 + ');'
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS decp
JOIN sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
    ON decp.plan_handle = deqs.plan_handle
WHERE decp.usecounts = 1
AND   decp.objtype = 'Adhoc'
AND   deqs.last_execution_time < DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE());

DECLARE plan_cursor CURSOR 
FORWARD_ONLY LOCAL  
FOR  
SELECT plan_handle 
FROM #plan_handles;  

OPEN plan_cursor;  
FETCH NEXT FROM plan_cursor 
    INTO @plan_handle_command
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN   

 PRINT @plan_handle_command;  
 EXEC(@plan_handle_command);  

FETCH NEXT FROM plan_cursor 
    INTO @plan_handle_command;  
END;  

CLOSE plan_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE plan_cursor;  
END;
```